# JavaScript function has not been executing as expected in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a basic asp.net web form application harmonized with JavaScript. There is a jQuery calendar and I try to send selected date to server.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalendarSample1.aspx.cs" Inherits="CalendarApplication.CalendarSample1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onclick="datepickerSendData()"/></p>
        <br />
        <input ID="lblDates" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnTamam" Text="Tamam" runat="server" OnClick="btnTamam_Click" />
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function datepickerSendData() {
        document.getElementById("lblDates").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }

</script>
```

The JavaScript function *datepickerSendData* has not behave as expected. I expect to change the content of the *lblDates* however, no change. Could you please point out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inner html as input is self closing tag.

```
document.getElementById("lblDates").value = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wonder why innerHTML does not work? In which circumstances we shall use innerHTML ?

Comment: Inner text or inner html is supposed to be in between open and close tags (<p>this is my inner text</p>). But a "self-closing tag" like <br /> (note slash is at the right, not at the left like in close-tags) cannot have inner anything because there is no open and close tag.